# load .Rdata file into list()

Tags: r

In R, `load(file = "file.Rdata")` will load all the variables as global variables. Is it possible to load all the variables contained in the .Rdata file into a list, so that it won't spoil the global variable space?

Comment: That's a different file format, different interface. I want to use the save/load with .Rdata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `load` inside `mget` with other `envir=`onment than the `.GlobalEnv`.

```
d1 <- d2 <- d3  <- d4 <- data.frame()
save(d1, d2, d3, d4, file="test.rda")
rm(d1, d2, d3, d4)

x <- mget(load("test.rda", envir=(NE. <- new.env())), envir=NE.)
ls()
# [1] "NE." "x" 
x
# $d1
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
# 
# $d2
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
# 
# $d3
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
# 
# $d4
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Answer (score 13):

You could assign it to a new environment and from there convert it into a list:

```
load("file.Rdata",  temp_env <- new.env())
env_list <- as.list(temp_env)
```

Comment: I just realised I accidentally loaded an .Rdata file using `readRDS` and it worked.  Does this work for single-object .Rdata files, or was the .Rdata file actually saved using `saveRDS` with incorrect file extension?  If the former, is using `readRDS("...Rdata")` a viable, albeit badly principled and unpredictable, solution?

Comment: @Earlien - the latter.